# ensure the changes to commit in a Java zip filesystem?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, filesystems

Briefing: I'm developing a system which must grant access to all the files of a project, it has to be an interface to open, upload and modify those files, i decided to store all of them (the files) in an archive (zip), in order to enhance the response time i decided not to unzip and then rezip all its contents, besides i decided to modify the zip as is, using the [Zip FileSystem Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) of java, but I'm facing many troubles because of the lack of info; when the user need an specific file i only decompress that file so the user can work on it, i monitor the changes in the file, then if i detect any change, i upload the file (replace) into the zip.

**the problem is:**

Since I'm using threads while saving the files into the archive (to prevent the GUI from freezing) the user can open others files and modify them even when another file is being saved, i want to have the changes as updated as possible into the archive to prevent the lost of information in case of a blackout but there is not a method like FileSystem.commit() or FileSystem.flush(), so the changes occurs into the archive just when I close the file system, but opening another file system takes too long, adding vulnerability to the lost of infomation to my system during the time that the another filesystem is initialized... any idea of how to commit changes or be always capable of have a way to save?

Opening two filesystems (once as a backup to do the operations while the other is being instantiated) does not work either, because they change the name of the file for a brief time but during that time the other instance may try to be created and fail because it cannot find the name for the file...

Greetings...

Comment: It feels like you've created a lot of work for yourself re-solving hard problems...  How important is it to use the Zip FileSystem?  What made you choose that over the standard filesystem?

Comment: the portability of the files, if i would have used the OS FileSystem, rather than saving the files in an archive, i would have to ensure the path an the existance of the files each time, since i have to run this in a very dynamic enviroment (a HUGE) intranet and the paths changes depending on your location on the net i decided to  store all the required files in an archive enshuring this way that all of the files will be there...

Comment: Hi, sorry for digging up an old question. Have you found a way to flush FileSystem without closing it?

Comment: Nope, I tried to be smart and implementing a pool but that didn't work either. I ended up adding a [System Shutdown Hook](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/) to finish doing all my saves even if my main app went down.

Does not cover blackouts but ... it's something

Comment: Yeah, I've used shutdown hook too, lol. I agree, it's not the most reliable solution, but for now it's enough for me. Thanks for answering.